# Remove duplication from rake tasks

Tags: ruby, task, rake, rakefile

I have three rake tasks that modify an instance variable and then call the task `:find`, This is the Rakefile:

```
@tags = ['OPTIMIZE', 'TODO', 'FIXME']

task :optimize do
   @tags = ['OPTIMIZE']
   Rake::Task["find"].invoke
end

task :todo do
   @tags = ['TODO']
   Rake::Task["find"].invoke
end

task :fixme do
   @tags = ['FIXME']
   Rake::Task["find"].invoke
end

task :find do
   # finds words depending on @tags
end
```

I would like to remove duplication from the Rakefile and make it more concise. How can I simplify (or combine) the :optimize, :todo, :fixme tasks in this Rakefile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rake tasks can take arguments, so instead of relying on an instance variable you can pass the tags in:

```
TAGS = ['OPTIMIZE', 'TODO', 'FIXME']

task :find, [:tags] do |task, args|
  # command lines can't pass an array, afaik; so if we pass the
  # tags in, we'll need them as a space separated list
  tags = if args[:tags]
           args[:tags].split(' ')
         else
           TAGS
         end

  puts "finding all tags marked: #{tags.inspect}"
end
```

and then on the command line:

```
% rake find[TODO OPTIMIZE] # may need escaped: rake find\[TODO\ OPTIMIZE\]
finding all tags marked: ["TODO", "OPTIMIZE"]
% rake find                  
finding all tags marked: ["OPTIMIZE", "TODO", "FIXME"]
```

and then, if you still want named tasks as aliases, passing certain arguments, you can pass them in through `invoke`:

```
TAGS.each do |tag|
  task tag.downcase.to_sym do
    Rake::Task["find"].invoke(tag)
  end
end
```

and calling them:

```
% rake todo
finding all tags marked: ["TODO"]
% rake fixme   
finding all tags marked: ["FIXME"]
% rake optimize
finding all tags marked: ["OPTIMIZE"]
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know I could create tasks inside the `#each` block. Also adding arguments to `:find` was very helpful.